# Ouath2 in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-oauth

I've followed the guide on https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2 for setting up the Oauth2 token for a google services very closely but i'm still not able to get the access token to work.

The error I'm receiving is Access not granted or expired. (line 454, file "Service", project "OAuth2")

Note* My project has already been whitelisted for the GMB API library and I have enabled it in the API console console. I retrieved a ClientID and ClientSecret from my project aswell.

```
//Oauth 2 Flow Start
function getGmbService() {
  // Create a new service with the given name. The name will be used when
  // persisting the authorized token, so ensure it is unique within the
  // scope of the property store.
  return OAuth2.createService('gmb')
  // Set the endpoint URLs, which are the same for all Google services.
  .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth')
  .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')

  // Set the client ID and secret, from the Google Developers Console.
  .setClientId('...')
  .setClientSecret('...')

  // Set the name of the callback function in the script referenced
  // above that should be invoked to complete the OAuth flow.
  .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')

  // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
  .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
  .setCache(CacheService.getUserCache())

  // Set the scopes to request (space-separated for Google services).
  .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage')

  // Below are Google-specific OAuth2 parameters.

  // Sets the login hint, which will prevent the account chooser screen
  // from being shown to users logged in with multiple accounts.
  .setParam('login_hint', Session.getActiveUser().getEmail())

  // Requests offline access.
  .setParam('access_type', 'offline')

  // Forces the approval prompt every time. This is useful for testing,
  // but not desirable in a production application.
  .setParam('approval_prompt', 'force');
}

function showSidebar() {
  var gmbService = getGmbService();
  if (!gmbService.hasAccess()) {
    var authorizationUrl = gmbService.getAuthorizationUrl();
    var template = HtmlService.createTemplate(
      '<a href="<?= authorizationUrl ?>" target="_blank">Authorize</a>. ' +
      'Reopen the sidebar when the authorization is complete.');
    template.authorizationUrl = authorizationUrl;
    var page = template.evaluate();
    DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(page);
  } else {
    Logger.log("No Access")
  }
}

function authCallback(request) {
  var gmbService = getGmbService();
  var isAuthorized = gmbService.handleCallback(request);
  if (isAuthorized) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success! You can close this tab.');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied. You can close this tab');
  }
}

//Oauth2 Flow Finish

function testRequest() {
  var gmbService = getGmbService();

  var payload = {
    "pageSize": 5
  }

  var options = {
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + gmbService.getAccessToken()
    },
    "method": 'GET',
    "payload": payload,
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  };


  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts",options)
  Logger.log(response);

}
```

Comment: Did you ever get an answer on this. I am having the same problem