# Access not granted or expired GMAIL API and Oauth2 / How to set email signatures using GMAIL API with a GSuite domain

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, gmail-api

i'm currently setting up an automatic signature system for every user of a google organisation but I haven't succeed to do so. I followed [this](https://dev.to/impression/google-suite-domain-level-signatures-with-google-scripts-187g) guide but I have the following error : `Service_.getAccessToken @ Service.gs:454`. The problem is that: I don't have access to the file `Service.gs` and when I googled my error, no answers, either on google's github or stack overflow's website suits me well.

Here is the code (from the guide, I of course changed the auth values):

```js
var accountsToIgnore = [
  'ignore-me@example.com',
  'noreply@example.com'
];

var auth = {
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nABCDE\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "name@project-id-XXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "INSERT_CLIENT_ID_HERE"
};

function go() {  
  var pageToken;
  var page;

  do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
      domain: 'example.com',
      orderBy: 'familyName',
      maxResults: 250,
      pageToken: pageToken,
      projection: 'full',
      // query: "email=your.email@example.com"
    });
    if (page.users) {
      page.users.forEach( function (user){
        if (accountsToIgnore.indexOf(user.primaryEmail) == -1) {

        var service = getOAuthService(user.primaryEmail);
        // Pull in the signatire template file contents into this variable 
        var signatureTemplate = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("signature").getContent();

          // Set up a userData variable, with some blank defaults as backups  
          var userData = {
            email: user.primaryEmail,
            firstName: user.name.givenName,
            lastName: user.name.familyName,
            jobTitle: "",
            showJobTitle: true,
            workingHours: "",
            directPhone: ""
          };
          if (typeof user.customSchemas !== 'undefined') { // Email sig settings are set
            if (typeof user.customSchemas.Email_signature !== 'undefined') {

              if (typeof user.customSchemas.Email_signature.Show_job_title_in_signature !== 'undefined' && user.customSchemas.Email_signature.Show_job_title_in_signature == false) {
                userData.showJobTitle = false; 
              }

              if (typeof user.customSchemas.Email_signature.Working_Hours_Description !== 'undefined' && user.customSchemas.Email_signature.Working_Hours_Description != "") {
                userData.workingHours = "<br /><br /><i>"+user.customSchemas.Email_signature.Working_Hours_Description+"</i><br />";
              }

            }
          }

          if (user.hasOwnProperty('organizations') && user.organizations[0].hasOwnProperty('title') && typeof user.organizations[0].title !== "undefined" && userData.showJobTitle == true) {
            userData.jobTitle = user.organizations[0].title+"<br />";
          }

          if (user.hasOwnProperty('phones') && Array.isArray(user.phones) && user.phones.length >0) {
            for (var p = 0; p < user.phones.length; p++) {
              if (user.phones[p].customType == "Google Voice") {
              // Depending on where in the world you are, you may need to adjust this formatting for your own needs... This replaces the +44 UK country code with a local "0" and adds a space after the local area code for formatting.
               userData.directPhone = "<br />D: " + user.phones[p].value.replace('+44', '0').replace('1158', '1158 '); 
              }
            }
          }

          // Replace the placeholders as seen in the signature.html file with the actual data from the userData variable set up earlier. 
          var userSig = signatureTemplate
          .replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "")
          .replace(/{email}/g, userData.email)
          .replace(/{firstName}/g, userData.firstName)
          .replace(/{lastName}/g, userData.lastName)
          .replace(/{jobTitle}/g, userData.jobTitle)
          .replace(/{workingHours}/g, userData.workingHours)
          .replace(/{directNumber}/g, userData.directPhone); 

          var sigAPIUrl = Utilities.formatString('https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/%s/settings/sendAs/%s',userData.email, userData.email);

          var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(sigAPIUrl, {
            method: "PUT",
            muteHttpExceptions: true,
            contentType: "application/json",
            headers: {
              Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
            },
            payload: JSON.stringify({
              'signature': userSig
            })
          });

          if (response.getResponseCode() !== 200) {
            Logger.log('There was an error: ' + response.getContentText());
          } else {
            Logger.log("Signature updated for "+user.primaryEmail);
          }
        }
      }); 

    } else {
      Logger.log('No users found.');
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
}

function getOAuthService(userId) {
  return OAuth2.createService("Signature Setter "+userId)
  .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
  .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth') // Added thanks to research
  .setClientId(auth.client_id) // same
  .setCallbackFunction('authCallback') // same
  .setPrivateKey(auth.private_key)
  .setIssuer(auth.client_email)
  .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
  .setSubject(userId)
  .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
  .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing');
}
```

The problem comes from the GMAIL API (100% errors on the google's API page) or from Google's OAuth2.

Here is some pages I found that are related to my problem:

- [github Issue](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/issues/192)
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55905114/ouath2-in-google-apps-script)

Full error code from apps.google: `Error: Access not granted or expired. Service_.getAccessToken @ Service.gs:454`

The credentials API *(the warning sign mean that it has been created automatically)*:
https://prnt.sc/yy8kg5

The files and services I have on google's apps script editor: https://prnt.sc/yy9dyw

Thanks for the help.

Comment: 1) Where did you get this code? - in other words it is a mess mixing different authorization methods together 2) You cannot object credentials from User IDs (getOAuthService). 3) You need to implement Domain Wide Delegation of Authority and correctly setup the service account for delegation. The service account then assumes the identity of a user. Be very careful protecting that service account. 4) You tagged `gmail`. Are you using Gmail or Google Workspace? Only the latter supports delegation. https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation

Comment: Access not granted or expired <-- the user has not authorized your application,  but as  @JohnHanley states you should be using a service account with domain wide delegation set up so that you have access to make these changes on behalf of a user if you want to automate this for the full domain, but you cant use service accounts with JavaScript.  With oauth2 your going to have to have each user login and grant your application access.

Comment: I am partially wrong in my comment. You need Domain Wide Delegation but you do not need to assume each user's identity. The service account does need delegation to manage the Workspace domain and add the signature to each account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the answers above and some personal research, I managed to set up an automatic signature with Google Console and Gmail API.

This is a step by step guide on how to set up the system.

DISCLAIMER: I'm not a professionnal and I *may* do mistakes (so feel free to correct me if i'm wrong :) ), but I still want to make this "guide"... maybe it can help someone, who knows ?

**1. GOOGLE APPS SCRIPTS**

*The steps are for the "New" Editor.*

1. Go to this [link (google apps scripts)](https://script.google.com/home) and create a new script.
2. Go to Settings > Check "Show `appsscript.json` manifest file in editor"
3. Editor > edit `appsscript.json` and add the oauthScopes:

```json
{
...
"oauthScopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
    ]
...
}
```

4. **In Editor tab:** add the [OAuth2](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2#setup) Library
5. add the `Gmail` and `AdminDirectory` Services
6. Copy this [code](https://gist.github.com/tholeb/c3775b7e747ea84fcc5febaa41872629) (based on [this](https://gist.github.com/tholeb/c3775b7e747ea84fcc5febaa41872629) page) and add your `OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY` and `OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_EMAIL` (you'll get it in the next part)
7. Create an new file HTML file named `signature.html`
8. **In Settings tab under "GCP Projet":** add your projet Number (you'll get it in the next part)

**2. GCP Project**

1. Go to this [link](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/) and create a project
2. On the project Info card, you can see the "Project Number" copy it, and paste it in the Google script settings tab.
3. Go to "APIs & Services" > Credentials > create a "Service Accounts" (you don't need roles)
4. Edit that Service Account you just created and check "Enable G Suite domain-wide delegation" under "Service account status" and create a new `json` key (this will make you dowload a file, **save it in a safe place, sharing this will result in a security leak in your G Suite domain** (don't forget to add the `OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY` and `OAUTH2_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_EMAIL` in the script).

**3. Google Admin (G Suite's Organization page)**

1. Go to Security > API Controls > "Manage Domain-wide delegation"
2. Add new and add this scopes:

```
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request
```

**4. Conclusion**

It's now the part where you test the stuff, don't forget to create your signature via the `signature.html` file; look at the `code.gs` file to create something with user's info, it's pretty explicit.

If you have any problems, feel free to post a comment, i'll do my best to answer you.